# How can I map and create a new column on dataframe corresponding to values in other 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe as shown below , My goal is to create a new column in the existing pandas dataframe and assign values to each row of that column based on the values of that in 2 different columns, The catch is that one of is nothing to do with arithmetic vallue meaning in one column I have sensor number and the other column I have the slope , Now in my new column which I want to create , I have to add a matching component for the corresponding sensor number and slope

[image]

I tried creating a dictionary  and mapping it to the pandas dataframe, But I am able to include only the sensor number there and not the corresponding slope

```
Component_LIST= {1015:'Blade_Fatigue', 215:'Hub=pitch_Bolts'}
df_fatigue_filtered['Component_List'] = 
df_fatigue_filtered['Sensor_Num'].map(Component_LIST)
```

Now the above code creates the component list for the corresponding sensor number , But every sensor has more than one slope , So just want to know how can the slope also be mapped here

Comment: Welcome to SO, you should always consider creating a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to test the complete question. And also add a input v/s output dataframes for us to test and verify (both as text and not [images](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)). here is a post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Please try to rewrite the question and show what you've tried already. Now it is not clear what you're trying to do.